# Issues with wine installing fonts

Tags: wine, fonts, git

I've tried so many things to fix this but for some reason nothing seems to have worked. I keep getting the pop-up error `Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/pacman/.wine terminate` I've tried doing `wineserver -k`. I've tried to reinstall wine. I've even tried deleting specific wine-related files manually to reinstall. I can run applications but keep running into an issue with the font displaying as a square for every character which I assume is related to my issue installing fonts. the error did not pop up until after I tried installing fonts using winetricks and something didn't work right. I tried adding dependency for 32 bit systems but that didn't help at all. I ran `git clone git://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git ~/wine-dirs/wine-source`. I made sure to add the winehq.key. I tried some other stuff I can't remember off the top of my head because I've been working on this issue for days but if I think of it I will update my post. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2 on a 64 bit machine. Please help me.

Comment: That's not an error. Please post the full output.

Comment: The full output of what?

Comment: Still, have an issue with this. that was all the window display and I haven't been able to output in the terminal. I might just reinstall to a version 19 after finals

Comment: Can you run winetricks in a terminal? Did you use the latest git version? (older versions stop working quickly)